# Remove VSTO 2010 manually

Tags: vsto

When I try to remove VSTO 2010 from my computer, it looks like it removed it, but after the deinstallation there is still the entry in "Programs and Features". When I try it again the normal install-routine is called.

I have to reinstall it because I can't build any Word-AddIns and I have to debug one because of a bug.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why you can't build your word addins? What makes you think it's because of VSTO2010? When you install VIsual Studio 2010, you get VSTO installed by default